# How do I specify a valid port when testing a client and server socket application?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I'm trying to connect a client to a server test program in C# using Sockets on my local machine.  However, I get the "server actively refused the connection" error for every port number I try.

How do I pick a valid port number to be able to just test out sockets between a sample client and server? Is there a valid port no. I can use for this scenario?

Comment: If this is Linux, make sure you bind to a port>1000 if you are executing this as a normal user since binding to ports<=1000 requires super user. Also make sure the port is not already taken by another program (Apache, SSH, etc)

Comment: Sounds like you may have a firewall running refusing connections of the ports that you.ve tried. If so, you'll need to open the port in your firewall before trying your client/server sample.

Comment: This is at work, so I might not have any control. Is this the case even if this is on my local machine?

Comment: Is the server on your localhost too? If not, can you see what ports are open using nmap? Or if you can get on that machine the netstat command will show what port is being used by the server.

Comment: Yes both server and client are on the same machine, but no port seems to be acceptable...

Comment: Are you trying to connect to yourself via an actual IP address or the IP loopback adapter (127.0.0.1 &hellip; "there no place like home" :D)). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_network_interface The firewall might see traffic to your actual IP address, while traffic to the loopback adapter it might not see.

Comment: Ok, you're connecting to yourself. If you do "netstat -aon", do you see the port the server is supposed to be listening on listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reasons you might not be able to bind to your desired port on the server of your choice:

- Your system has a firewall configured to prevent outbound connections on the port in question.
- Your network imposes such a restriction, either via a firewall or proxy/gateway.
- The server's network won't allow inbound connections on the port in question, either via firewall or proxy/gateway.
- The server itself is firewalled and won't allow inbound connections on the port in question.

Finally, it's always possible that the *daemon* in question on the server isn't running.

Check your ports:

- **0–1023 (0x000–0x03FF)**
  are reserved for "well-known ports" and typically have certain restrictions, at least for the server end of things. It wouldn't make much sense to require special permissions for a client to use a well-known port.
- **1024–65535 (0x0400–0xFFFF)**
  are putatively open for anybody to use.

  However...every system has a range of ports designated as [*ephemeral ports*](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html) that should not normally be used. Berkeley sockets used 1024–4999 as the emphemeral range, but that range varies from system to system and is [usually] configurable.